# `TypeError: member.hasPermission() is not a function` when checking permissions in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a **has-permission** command for my Discord bot, which takes two arguments: the user to check, and the permission to check for. You can see the code in the [bot's GitHub repository](https://github.com/JavascriptLearner815/speedo-bot) (the `config.json` file is hidden due to it containing private information about my bot application).

Discord Screenshot:
[image: Discord Screenshot]

The bot just replies `there was an error trying to execute that command!`.

Console Screenshot:
[image: Console Screenshot]

The console just says `TypeError: member.hasPermission is not a function`.

Is there any way around this? It seems like this is the only problem I am having making this command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
```

instead of:

```js
const member = message.mentions.users.first();
```

as `message.mentions.members.first()` will be the first mentioned member in the message, and you need to use `Member.hasPermission()`. When using `message.mentions.users.first().hasPermission()`, you're using `User.hasPermission()` and you just can't.