# TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined Discord.js javascript

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, discord.js

I am working on a mute command and got this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

This is my code

```
const person = message.mentions.users.first() 
person.roles.add(muterole.id)
```

I have tried:
person.addRole but it also doesnt work
and person.roles.add(muterole) but it also doesnt work

Any Idea why? thanks

Comment: You've to define `person.roles` before using any of its methods.

Comment: @Teemu how to do that? Sorry I am new to coding

Comment: @KhairaDenisa it would be better to find the mentioned users you will have to do it manually. Source: https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html#how-discord-mentions-work

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `message.mentions.members.first()`. A `User` doesn't have any role, because it represents a user on Discord, and a `Member` has roles, it represents a `User` in a `Guild` ([another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63420212/11856499)).

```js
const person = message.mentions.members.first() 
person.roles.add(muterole.id)
```

Comment: Ok that works but now there is this error: 
```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not an Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.
```

Comment: Try to log your `muterole` variable, and make sure it is not somehow undefined